# How is REST api versioning implemented technically?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, webapi

I am working on a REST api which needs to be refactored. This will be a breaking change so the original api is to be made as v1 and the new refactored api will be known as v2. The versioning will be implemented at url level.

I want to understand technically how to approach this problem. Should I create a copy of the project and make the changes or should I make changes on the same project and then how do I expose the project as separate verisons?

Comment: are you using `.NET Core` based api's ?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement versioning like below. In `Startup.cs`, `ConfigureServices()` you can do the following:

```
services.AddApiVersioning(option =>
{
    option.ReportApiVersions = true;
    option.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    option.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    option.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
});
```

Now, you can have multiple versions of Controllers like below:

```
namespace APIVersions.Controllers
{
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get() => Ok(new string[] { "value1" });
    }
}
```

Version 2:

```
namespace APIVersions.Controllers3
{
    [ApiVersion("2.0")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get() => Ok(new string[] { "value1" });
    }
}
```

Now, in your browser you can have `?api-version=2` which will hit the second version.

Also, you can do this:

```
namespace APIVersions.Controllers
{
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [ApiVersion("2.0")]
    [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get() => Ok(new string[] { "value1" });

        [HttpGet, MapToApiVersion("2.0")]
        public IActionResult GetV3() => Ok(new string[] { "value3" });
    }
}
```

This way, you can call the desired Get method.

Reference: https://www.talkingdotnet.com/support-multiple-versions-of-asp-net-core-web-api/

Answer (score 1):

Both REST api endpoints must be available after your refactor. Both of them must exist in your code, so just add another controller endpoint in the existing controller e.g.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("v1/ElectricityAll")]
    public IActionResult ElBlockedGetV1()
    {
        return new JsonResult(_context.ElBlockeds.ToList());
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("v2/ElectricityAll")]
    public IActionResult ElBlockedGetV2()
    {
        return new JsonResult(_context.ElBlockeds.Where(x=>x.Status == Status.Active).ToList());
    }
```